# Compile python with Pyinstaller failure : Failed to execute script Myfile

Tags: python, pyinstaller

After I compile `myfile.py` to `exe` with `pyinstaller` to one file, that file is working on my computer but not on others' computers.
error >>> Failed to execute script Myfile

I use this command

`pyinstaller --onefile Myfile.py`

Comment: Your computer and others are the same OS and version ???

Comment: yes , same version.
windows10
I use python3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your exe with --debug=all and run it in a console. Provide the output to help people help you.
Refer to https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#getting-debug-messages to get more details if needed